# Making a cell in a JTable editable - the default value of the cell

Tags: java, jtable

I am working with Java, and I am trying to make a cell in JTable to be editable. My class implements TableModel and extends AbstractTableModel (so that I can use the method `fireTableCellUpdated(rowIndex, columnIndex))`, and I have implemented the methods `isCellEditable()` and `setValueAt()`.
I represent a single cell in the table as an object of class Cell.

Now here is my problem: the cell is already editable, and when I click on it, the cursor appears in the cell, however, there appears also a string in the cell like this: `Cell@1e63e3d`. I delete this string and put in the cell the value, which I want to put, then click Enter and it works fine. But I want when I click on the cell there to appear nothing, an empty string, and not `Cell@1e63e3d`. And I don't know how to set this empty string as default and where.

My Cell class stores information (characteristics) about the cell like color of the cell, and its value as instance variables.

Please tell me if you need more information.

Answer (score 7):

Have you set a [`TableCellRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) and [`TableCellEditor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) for your [`JTable`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html)?

**For displaying a cell**, the `TableCellRenderer` is used to render the contents for a location from the `TableModel`. By default, it will use the `toString` method of the `Object` in that location, so that would explain the `Cell@1e63e3d` being displayed in the cell -- that is the result of the `toString` method being called on your `Cell` object.

By writing a custom cell renderer (a class that implements `TableCellRenderer`), you'll be able to return a `Component` you want to use to display the `Cell` object, using the [`getTableCellRendererComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html#getTableCellRendererComponent(javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)) method. In your case, you may want to subclass a `JLabel` which implements `TableCellRenderer` and will set the contents of the label to reflect the contents of your `Cell` object.

**As for editing a cell**, the `TableCellEditor` receives the `Object` from the `TableModel` when you want to edit a cell with in the `JTable`. The `TableCellEditor` will return a `Component` which is used to edit the cell contents (the `Object`) using the [`getTableCellEditorComponent`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html#getTableCellEditorComponent(javax.swing.JTable,%20java.lang.Object,%20boolean,%20int,%20int)) method.

In the case you provide, I think that making a `JTextField` which implements the `TableCellEditor` interface will be able to do the job for you. When you override the `getTableCellEditorComponent`, check that you have an instance of the `Cell` object (i.e. `object instanceof Cell`) and if that's the case, initialize your `JTextField` to contain the contents of your `Cell` object that you want to display or edit.

**Recommended reading:** I found the [Rendering cells in Swing's JTable component](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtable/) article from IBM developerWorks to be quite helpful in learning how to deal with `JTable`s and their cell rendering and editing features. In particular, the [Creating custom renderers](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtable/#h1) and [Editiing table cells](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-jtable/#h3) sections may be of interest.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using an appropriate [`TableCellEditor`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellEditor.html) to display the component for editing?

```
class MyTableCellEditor
        extends DefaultCellEditor
{
    @Override
    public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(
            JTable table,
            Object value,
            boolean isSelected,
            int row,
            int column)
    {
        final JTextField c = (JTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(
            table,
            ((Cell) value).text, // edit the text field of Cell
            isSelected,
            row,
            column);

        c.selectAll(); // automatically select the whole string in the cell
        return c;
    }
}
```

You will need to tell your table to use this custom cell editor, in addition to the custom cell renderer.

```
myTable.setDefaultEditor(Cell.class, new MyTableCellEditor());
```